# Why does SO keep revisions for when a post gets locked, unlocked, etc...?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list

I'm wondering why a revision is created when a post is locked, unlocked, protected, unprotected, etc...

What is the benefit of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that a new revision is created—those records aren't numbered. Instead, they simply serve as records in the revision history so that members can see who took action on a particular post.

Comment: thank you. Can you please explain what you mean by "those records aren't numbered"?

Comment: @Mohamad If you look at [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/52764/revisions), you'll see that the revisions are numbered on the left hand side, but the protection and unprotection aren't.